# how to grep for multiple words in a line?

Tags: python

I have the following code where I am trying to grep for "Warning" *and* "wcnss_proc\bt" in a given input file passsed as first argument,however the output.txt is grepping for only "Warning"...can anypoint what is wrong in the below code?i want to grep for both "Warning" and "wcnss_proc\bt" for all the lines in input file

```
import sys

def filter_log(input_file, output_file, strs):
    with open(input_file, "r") as input, open(output_file, "w") as output:
        output.writelines(filter(lambda x: any([s in x for s in strs]), input.readlines()))

# here is just searched for "Warning", add other stuff

filter_log(sys.argv[1], "output.txt", ["Warning","wcnss_proc\bt"])
```

Comment: did you mean r"wcnss_proc\bt" - raw string form ? (backslashes are nasty)

Comment: @vish -  r"wcnss_proc\bt"  helps but I want to grep for both "Warning" and  r"wcnss_proc\bt" ..currently above logic is like an "or"..any line with word "Warning" or "wcnss_proc\bt" is getting stored in output.txt..how to make it an "AND" condition?

Comment: @user2639990: Just use `all` instead of `and`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` is an escape character. do you mean `\\b`?

Comment: = currently above logic is like an "or"..any line with word "Warning" or "wcnss_proc\bt" is getting stored in output.txt..how to make it an "AND" condition?

Comment: Can you give an example line in the file? Change the "any" to "all" could be it.

Comment: To switch to requiring both strings to be present, use `all` instead of `any`.